pasar informacion de una db a otra db
Tengo 2 bases de datos iguales, quiero agregar información de una db a db.Ejemplo en una db tengo informacion de 01/01/2024 hasta 05/05/2024, y en la otra tengo informacion desde 06/05/2024 a la fecha, quiero unificar toda a una sola db

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Y cual es el problema??? no digas no se.. que intentaste o averiguaste o probaste??? porque la solucion simple es hace un dump y subilo a la otra...

¿cuál es la pregunta?
